# How to make LPeg.match return nil

Tags: lua, lpeg

I'm currently getting familiar with the LPeg parser module. For this I want to match a version string (e.g. `11.4`) against a *list*.

Such a list is a string with a tight syntax that can also contain *ranges*. Here is an EBNF-like, but in any case quite simple grammar (I write it down because LPeg code below can be a bit difficult to read):

```
S = R, { ',', R }
R = N, [ '-', N ]
N = digit+, [ '.', digit+ ]
```

An example string would be `1-9,10.1-11,12`. Here is my enormous code:

```
local L = require "lpeg"
local LV, LP, LC, LR, floor = L.V, L.P, L.C, L.R, math.floor
local version = "7.25"

local function check(a, op, b)
    if op and a+0 <= version and version <= b+0 then
        return a..op..b -- range
    elseif not op and floor(version) == floor(a+0) then
        return a        -- single item
    end
end
local grammar = LP({ "S",
    S = LV"R" * (LP"," * LV"R")^0,
    R = LV"V" * (LC(LP"-") * LV"V")^-1 / check,
    V = LC(LV"D" * (LP"." * LV"D")^-1),
    D = (LR("09")^1),
})
function checkversion(str)
    return grammar:match(str)
end
```

So you would call it like `checkversion("1-7,8.1,8.3,9")` and if the current version is not matched by the list you *should* get `nil`.

Now, the trouble is, if all calls to `check` return nothing (meaning, if the versions do not match), `grammar:match(...)` will actually have no captures and so return the **current position** of the string. But this is exactly what I *do not* want, I want `checkversion` to return `nil` or `false` if there is no match and something that evaluates to true otherwise, actually just like `string:match` would do.

If I on the other hand return `false` or `nil` from `check` in case of a non-match, I end up with return values from match like `nil, "1", nil, nil` which is basically impossible to handle.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the pattern I eventually used:

```
nil_capturing_pattern * lpeg.Cc(nil)
```

I incorporated it into the grammar in the `S` rule (Note that this also includes changed grammar to "correctly" determine version order, since in version numbering "4.7" < "4.11" is true, but not in calculus)

```
local Minor_mag = log10(Minor);
local function check(a, am, op, b, bm)
    if op then
        local mag = floor(max(log10(am), log10(bm), Minor_mag, 1))+1;
        local a, b, v = a*10^mag+am, b*10^mag+bm, Major*10^mag+Minor;

        if a <= v and v <= b then
            return a..op..b;
        end
    elseif a == Major and (am == "0" or am == Minor) then
        return a.."."..am;
    end
end

local R, V, C, Cc = lpeg.R, lpeg.V, lpeg.C, lpeg.Cc
local g = lpeg.P({ "S",
    S = V("R") * ("," * V("R"))^0 * Cc(nil), 
    R = (V("Vm") + V("VM")) * (C("-") * (V("Vm") + V("VM")))^-1 / check,
    VM = V("D") * Cc("0"),
    Vm = V("D") * "." * V("D"),
    D = C(R("09")^1),
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can or `+` it with a constant capture of nil:

```
grammar = grammar + lpeg.Cc(nil)
```

Comment: That's the direction I wanted to go in! It doesn't work however (because the branch is not captured if the grammar matches, even if it's a constant capture), *but* it does work with **`*`** (concatenation) instead the `+`. This way the return list is always followed by one `nil` even if it's an empty list! If you would change that little thing in the answer this one would be my choice

Comment: Do you always want it to be followed by a `nil` though? Maybe you should be doing `check` as a match time capture?

Comment: The `nil` does not hurt, even if I decide to put all return values into a table, the trailing `nil` would be discarded, only `select('#', ...)` would return an unexpected value. And as for the match time capture -- I don't really see how it would help. Though adding a function capture instead of the `* Cc(nil)` would be possible.

Comment: A match time capture would ensure that a non-matching version wouldn't match :)

Comment: But if I return false/nil/no-value, the match fails. So to evaluate the rest of the version list, I would have to provide an alternative path in the grammar that matches the same field without capturing it. And then, if no matches occur, `grammar:match` would still return a number. So I'm not sure what benefit that would be.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple returns from `match` are not impossible to handle, if you catch them in a way that makes handling them easier. I added a function `matched` that does that, and added the fallback return of `false` to your `check`.

```
do
    local L = require "lpeg"
    local LV, LP, LC, LR, floor = L.V, L.P, L.C, L.R, math.floor
    local version = 6.25

    local function check(a, op, b)
        if op and a+0 <= version and version <= b+0 then
            return a..op..b -- range
        elseif not op and floor(version) == floor(a+0) then
            return a        -- single item
        end
        return false
    end
    local grammar = LP({ "S",
        S = LV"R" * (LP"," * LV"R")^0,
        R = LV"V" * (LC(LP"-") * LV"V")^-1 / check,
        V = LC(LV"D" * (LP"." * LV"D")^-1),
        D = (LR("09")^1),
    })

    local function matched(...)
        local n = select('#',...)
        if n == 0 then return false end
        for i=1,n do
            if select(i,...) then return true end
        end
        return false
    end

    function checkversion(ver,str)
        version = ver
        return matched(grammar:match(str))
    end
end
```

I enclosed the whole thing in `do ... end` so that the local `version` which is used here as an upvalue to `check` would have constrained scope, and added a parameter to `checversion()` to make it clearer to run through few test cases. For example:

```
cases = { 1, 6.25, 7.25, 8, 8.5, 10 }
for _,v in ipairs(cases) do
    print(v, checkversion(v, "1-7,8.1,8.3,9"))
end
```

When run, I get:

```
C:\Users\Ross\Documents\tmp\SOQuestions>q18793493.lua
1       true
6.25    true
7.25    false
8       true
8.5     true
10      false

C:\Users\Ross\Documents\tmp\SOQuestions>
```

Note that either `nil` or `false` would work equally well in this case. It just feels saner to have collected a list that can be handled as a normal Lua array-like table without concern for the holes.

Comment: Okay, maybe *impossible* was a bit overstated, of course I was aware that I can iterate over the returned list - but I was actually looking for something a bit more elegant and better scaling than iterating over all return values --- again.